# ASPNET Identity: Must declare the scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, asp.net-identity

I use ODBC for connection to Asp.NET Identity database. But I have an exception: "Must declare the scalar variable "@0"". The ecxeption is called from "public SimpleMembershipInitializer()". Whan should I do?? Sorry my english)

```
private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
{
    public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

        /*try
        {*/
            using (var context = new UsersContext())
            {
                if (!context.Database.Exists())
                {
                    // SimpleMembership Creating database schema migration without Entity Framework
                    ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                }
            }
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true); // HERE, AN EXCEPTION IS THROWN

            SimpleRoleProvider roles = (SimpleRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;
            SimpleMembershipProvider membership = (SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;

            if (!roles.RoleExists("Moderator"))
            {
                roles.CreateRole("Moderator");
            }
            if (!roles.RoleExists("Admin"))
            {
                roles.CreateRole("Admin");
            }
            if (membership.GetUser("Admin", false) == null)
            {
                membership.CreateUserAndAccount("Admin", "1");
                roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "Admin" }, new[] { "Admin" });
            }
        /*}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to initialize the database ASP.NET Simple Membership.", ex);
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, post the affected code.

Comment: `SimpleMembershipInitializer` is not part of Asp.Net Identity